# Configuring Entity Framework outside of dbContext Assembly

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

My application has a Data Access layer (*DAL*) which contains the **dbContext** definition. I'm using a SqlServer database.

Since the startup project is an **ASP.NET Core MVC** project (*UI*), I copied the **App.Config** from the *DAL* project to the *UI* project.

The thing is that the *UI* project does not reference the *DAL* project (I'm using dependency injection to get my concrete types); thus, the *UI* project can't find the **SqlServer** provider, and I get the following error:

> The Entity Framework provider type
>   'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices,
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file
>   for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'
>   could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is
>   used and that the assembly is available to the running application.

Comment: Saw your comment on your desire for loose coupling.  I have been down this road many times.  Could you provide an example of how you are trying to pass data from your DAL layer to your UI layer?

Comment: The UI Project references the Domain project, and the DAL project also references the Domain project. Then I have a 'container' project referencing both the Domain and DAL projects; this is where the wiring up happens. I call this code from the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method in my ASP.NET Core MVC project.

Comment: @trevorc: Do you have a better approach toward this?

Comment: I do (I believe). It doesn't have the 100% loose coupling you are after but it is decoupled nicely and lends itself to upgrade/changes over time.  The comment below by @T.S. Is quite accurate.  I just put up a [seed project](https://github.com/trevorchunestudy/netcore-ef6-seed) on my github page that may prove to be useful.  If you have any questions let me know. We can discuss in chat.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure the provider DLL gets copied to the output directory of your web app.. Either by referencing it, or by copying in a post build event